# Stacking A tags in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

How would I make these A tags sit on top of each other instead of next to each other.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
<h1>Unlisted Games</h1>
<a href="Website.com">Capture the Flag</a>
<a href="REEEEEEEEEEE.com">Flappy Bird</a>
<a href="google.net">Snake</a>
```

Comment: Have a look into the difference between "block elements" and "inline elements" for html. a tags are inline elements and so naturally line up together. There are many ways to sort this, setting them as block elements works, but also an unordered list (once you style away the bullets).

Comment: turn them into blocks via display . any value is fine(and different ) a long as it is not inline / inline-x ; ;)

Answer (score 3):

add display: block; to a tags

```
a{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: since they are sibllings of a block elemet, turning the display to a block level seems the most natural, even that CSS has nothing to do with semantic nor any effects on the DOM .CSS is only about styling and display is fine ;)

Comment: Could you give me answer approval? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick, dirty and simple solution, all you need to do is insert line breaks (`br`) after each A element:

```
<h1>Unlisted Games</h1>
<a href="Website.com">Capture the Flag</a><br>
<a href="REEEEEEEEEEE.com">Flappy Bird</a><br>
<a href="google.net">Snake</a><br>
```

However, as has been pointed out in the comments, it's worth noting that this won't give you a great amount of control over the line height/spacing, so where that is desired, you should the alternative methods suggested by other posters instead.

Comment: I wouldn't do this as you won't have precise control over line height and line spacing because of the break tags.

Comment: @NathanielFlick You're right... I'd say on balance that for just some quick-and-dirty thing it's probably fine, but it's probably not ideal if you need that control (I hadn't thought of the line spacing issue). I'll edit my post shortly to this effect.

Comment: just use display, that's what it is made for ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify HTML markup, than add `<br>` between links.

If it has to be just CSS task, I'd do

```
a {float: left; clear: left;}
```

If you add `display: block` as someone answers you, 100% will be active for a click, it can be wrong. But links will be where you want to have them.

Comment: display:grid/flex/table are also other block elements with different behavior ;) display:table will shrink the element to its content ...

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: sure, there is a million ways how to do it, depends on context. But I don't know why you write it me, try to write other options to the OP ;-)

Comment: I do not think float is the best first choice(to advise to a beginner)  and it comes with sides effect you might have to deal with later on ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to display your .

It would looks like something like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Unlisted Games</title>
    <style>
        h1{
            text-align:center;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }
        a{
            color: black;
            font-size: 30px;
       }
       .vertical-align {
            display: inline
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
    <h1>Unlisted Games</h1>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="Website.com">Capture the Flag</a></li>
    <li><a href="REEEEEEEEEEE.com">Flappy Bird</a></li>
    <li><a href="google.net">Snake</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know you could do : `a{display:list-item;}` without touching the HTML , if you wanted the links to look like a list ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few ways via `display` to complete other answers , it can be more

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  display: table;
}

hr~a {
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  background: pink;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div a {
  align-self: start;
  background: lightblue;
}
div + hr ~a {
display:list-item;
background:green;
margin-left:2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Unlisted Games</h1>
<code>display:table</code>
<a href="Website.com">Capture the Flag</a>
<a href="REEEEEEEEEEE.com">Flappy Bird</a>
<a href="google.net">Snake</a>
<hr>

<code>display:block</code> +
<code>width: max-content;</code>
<a href="Website.com">Capture the Flag</a>
<a href="REEEEEEEEEEE.com">Flappy Bird</a>
<a href="google.net">Snake</a>
<div>
  <h1>Unlisted Games</h1>
  <p>Inside a <code>display:flex</code> parent set to <code>flex-direction:column</code></p>
  <a href="Website.com">Capture the Flag</a>
  <a href="REEEEEEEEEEE.com">Flappy Bird</a>
  <a href="google.net">Snake</a>
</div>
<hr>
<code>display:list-item</code>+
<code>width: max-content;</code>
  <a href="Website.com">Capture the Flag</a>
  <a href="REEEEEEEEEEE.com">Flappy Bird</a>
  <a href="google.net">Snake</a>
```